# openGraph in Next.js with next-seo

Tags: next.js, seo, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to customize my site's SEO using next-seo in Next.js.

Everything looks good except the image is not being rendered when I'm sharing the link in Facebook

When using Facebook developers debugger I'm getting this error message:

> Inferred Property
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

This is my openGraph configuration :

```js
title: 'Site title here',
description: `Site description here`,
openGraph: {
    type: 'website',
    locale: 'fr_FR',
    url: 'url here',
    site_name: 'name here',
    description: `description here`,
    title: 'Title here',
    image: 'https://prismic-io.s3.amazonaws.com/gary-blog%2F3297f290-a885-4cc6-9b19-3235e3026646_default.jpg',
    imageWidth: 1200,
    imageHeight: 1200,
  },
```

Comment: Images are passed as an `images` array to the `openGraph` object. See https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo#open-graph-examples.

Answer (score 0):

openGraph props as a type of object inside it, image is not a parameter, instead images is a parameter as a type of read-only OpenGraphMedia[], which means OpenGraphMedia is an object containing url, caption, alternativeText.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).